# txList.length returns different value for different Solidity versions

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc, plasma

I have RLPReader smart contract, took it [from here](https://github.com/FourthState/plasma-mvp-rootchain/blob/master/contracts/Libraries/RLP.sol).

And I have a function untouched for a while:

```
function deposit(bytes txBytes) public pure returns (uint) {
    RLP.RLPItem[] memory txList = txBytes.toRLPItem().toList();
    require(txList.length == 15);
    //...
}
```

Everything worked fine until I changed `pragma solidity ^0.4.18;` to `pragma solidity ^0.4.24`. I just change this one line and my test fails now.
I found that code fails on this line `require(txList.length == 15);` because previously `txList.length` was `BigNumber { s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 15 ] }`, but after upgrade to `^0.4.24` it's `BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 4 ] }` and I can't find why. Does anybody know what changes can affect on this code?

Comment: What data are you parsing? It look like a bug, you should report to the RPL library developers or the solidity compiler.